# if statement not working when placed in the function

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement

I have a problem with my `if` statement that is tasked with checking the input fields and giving me a message that will say if my fields are empty. The problem is I wanted to put it inside of a function so that if the `if` statement is `false` it would automatically proceed on with the function and do the task it was meant to do.

As you can see almost all of the functions have the `if` statement in them.
(I'm making a calculator).

Oh, and please use this basic JavaScript as I did. My knowledge of JavaScript is still not very good and since I'm doing this for a school assignment I should probably use this type of codes.

I will post my code here:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script>


      function pozdrav()
      {
        alert("Unesite dva broja te odaberite željenu operaciju:");
      }
      function brisi()
      {

        var prvibroj = "";
        var drugibroj = "";
        var rezultat = "";
        document.getElementById("prvibroj").value = prvibroj;
        document.getElementById("drugibroj").value = drugibroj;
        document.getElementById("rezultat").value = rezultat;
      }
      function boja(elem)
      {
        var elem = elem.style.color="red";
      }
      function staraboja(elem)
      {
        var elem = elem.style.color="black";
      }
      function promjena()
      {
        var rezultat="";
        document.getElementById("rezultat").value = rezultat;
      }
      function plus()
      {
        var prvibroj = parseInt(document.getElementById("prvibroj").value);
        var drugibroj = parseInt(document.getElementById("drugibroj").value);

        if(prvibroj == "" || drugibroj == "")
        {

          alert("Za ispravan izračun, morate unijeti oba broja!");
        } 
        else
        {
          var rezultat = prvibroj + drugibroj;
          document.getElementById("rezultat").value = rezultat;
        }
      }
      function minus()
      {
        var prvibroj = parseInt(document.getElementById("prvibroj").value);
        var drugibroj = parseInt(document.getElementById("drugibroj").value);
        if(prvibroj == "" || drugibroj == "")
        {
          alert("Za ispravan izračun, morate unijeti oba broja!");
        } 
        else
        {
          var rezultat = prvibroj - drugibroj;
          document.getElementById("rezultat").value = rezultat;
        } 
      }
      function mnozenje()
      {
        var prvibroj = parseInt(document.getElementById("prvibroj").value);
        var drugibroj = parseInt(document.getElementById("drugibroj").value);
        if(prvibroj == "" || drugibroj == "")
        {
          alert("Za ispravan izračun, morate unijeti oba broja!");
        } 
        else
        {
          var rezultat = prvibroj * drugibroj;
          document.getElementById("rezultat").value = rezultat;
        }
      }
      function djeljenje()
      {
        var prvibroj = parseInt(document.getElementById("prvibroj").value);
        var drugibroj = parseInt(document.getElementById("drugibroj").value);
        if(prvibroj == "" || drugibroj == "")
        {
          alert("Za ispravan izračun, morate unijeti oba broja!");
        } 
        else
        {
          var rezultat = prvibroj / drugibroj;
          document.getElementById("rezultat").value = rezultat;
        }
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="pozdrav()">
    <h2>Kalkulator</h2>
    <p>Prvi broj:</p>
    <input type="text" id="prvibroj" onmouseover="boja(this)" onmouseout="staraboja(this)" onchange="promjena()" /> <br />
    <p>Drugi broj:</p>
    <input type="text" id="drugibroj" onmouseover="boja(this)" onmouseout="staraboja(this)" onchange="promjena()" /> <br />
    <p>Rezultat:</p>
    <input type="text" id="rezultat" onmouseover="boja(this)" onmouseout="staraboja(this)" onchange="promjena()" /> <br /> <br />
    <input type="button" value="+" onclick="plus()"/>
    <input type="button" value="-" onclick="minus()"/>
    <input type="button" value="*" onclick="mnozenje()"/>
    <input type="button" value="/" onclick="djeljenje()"/>
    <input type="button" value="C" onclick="brisi()"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, what problem are you having and where in your code are you having it?

Comment: I believe the point of school assignments is to figure them out yourself, not outsource to Stack Overflow... Otherwise, `prvibroj` is being set to the result of `parseInt`, and so will never be the empty string. It will be a number or `NaN`.

Comment: @P Cmrecki Looks like you are parsing the values to integers, but your if condition is checking for empty strings.

Comment: if one or more of the fields in my calculator is blank when i press any of the buttons (except C) a pop up message should appear saying that i did not fill in the require fields.
The problem in the code is everywhere where the if statement appears.
I just need someone to solve the first one in function plus.

Comment: Mike McCaughan, I am free to use the internet and do on it whatever I want except copy the same exact code from my classmates.

Comment: Ok so if you want to check all fields then you will need one function that calls all the rest of your functions which you then call onclick of all your buttons

Comment: thanks, i will try that

Comment: Thank you guys, its working now:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are converting your input value to integer

```
var drugibroj = parseInt(document.getElementById("drugibroj").value);
```

the value in drugibroj if the field is blank  will be NaN, So you should check for Nan in you if condition instead of ""

```
 if(isNaN(prvibroj) || isNaN(drugibroj))
 {

      alert("Za ispravan izračun, morate unijeti oba broja!");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this:

```
var prvibroj = parseInt(document.getElementById("prvibroj").value);
```

which if `document.getElementById("prvibroj").value` is empty will set `prvibroj` to `NaN`.

Then you are comparing this variable as if it was a string:

```
if(prvibroj == "" || drugibroj == "")
```

but if the values are empty it's the same as `if (NaN == "" || NaN == "")` which will always evaluate to false (NaN is never equal to anything).

So one solution is to check for `NaN` instead of empty string. For example:

```
var prvibroj = parseInt(document.getElementById("prvibroj").value);
var drugibroj = parseInt(document.getElementById("drugibroj").value);

if(isNaN(prvibroj) || isNaN(drugibroj))
{

  alert("Za ispravan izračun, morate unijeti oba broja!");
} 
else
{
  var rezultat = prvibroj + drugibroj;
  document.getElementById("rezultat").value = rezultat;
}
```

(and the same for all the functions)